# How to Fix PHP Deprecated: Function create_function() is deprecated

Tags: php, wordpress, php-7.2

I upgraded from `PHP` `5.3` to `7.2` and am getting the following error on 2 lines of code:

> PHP Deprecated:  Function create_function() is deprecated

I searched the forum and tried various forms of code, but none of them worked.

Code 1:

```
add_action( 'widgets_init', create_function( '', 'register_widget("layerslider_widget");' ) );
```

Code 2:

```
add_action( 'widgets_init', create_function( '', 'register_widget( "advanced_featured_page_widget" );' ) );
```

Thanks for your assistance!

Answer (score 12):

create_function was used to create anonymous function. So you can simply change it to `function() {}`

In example:

instead

```
add_action( 'widgets_init', create_function( '', 'register_widget("layerslider_widget");' ) );
```

use

```
add_action( 'widgets_init', function() {
    register_widget("layerslider_widget");
} );
```